# I got a new monitor, and now an LED light on my motherboard turns on after a while after reboots

Tags: intel, monitor, motherboard

I replaced my two 1080p monitors with a single 4k monitor.
It looks great. I am using it now to type this.

It uses the DisplayPort (DP) out on my motherboard, where I am using the integrated Intel graphics chipset (no dedicated graphics card).

In order to connect it to the monitor, I use a DP to HDMI converter that is plugged into the DP out, and uses an HDMI cable to connect.
Everything is working at 4k resolution and 60hz.

But I see this new white LED light on my motherboard turn on after a while, and it makes me nervous.  I've never seen it before now.  (Edit: It is the "VGA" LED on the MoBo.  The specific model of the Mobo, also, is: TUF Gaming b460-PRO AsusTek)

I checked the temperatures and everything is fine (the hottest I ever see it is 40C).

But I haven't any other idea what could be the issue.

When I looked for answers, I found dozens of "help" articles, all of which said "Here's about 40 things it *could* be!"  And then no real explanation of how to check if it is any given thing, without massive, drastic steps (like "Just replace the CPU with a new one!").

Please help me prevent a possible explosion, and figure out *how* to troubleshoot this.

Edit: I am mostly hoping that Ubuntu has some sort of command that lets me communicate with the motherboard, that I might know more about what is making that light feel like turning on at all.

Comment: This question will be almost impossible for anyone to answer given the lack of specifics. That said, it does not seem to be related to Ubuntu, so it may be better to ask on a hardware enthusiast site. Be sure to include the make/model of the motherboard and, ideally, a clear  photo of the motherboard with the light on and another with the light off so that people may be able to identify circuitboard markings that identify the purpose of the LED.

Comment: Thanks.  Should I delete this post, then?

Comment: Yeah I just thought Ubuntu might have some sort of shell command like $sudo wtf_mobo fullanalysis -k -n -bbq

Comment: Did you look here https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1042678/  or here  https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=86s2l65Gw1Y ?  Those might help you identify what the led is.

Comment: The answer is dumb, but simple:
If the monitor is turned on before the computer, no LED light.
If the computer is turned on before the monitor, LED light.

Not sure what use this has, but this is the answer.  So I just turn on the monitor first.